# while loop problem, calculate days from period

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

Table Order

```
OrderID | FromDate   | ToDate    
4523691 | 2015-01-23 | 2015-04-22     
4523692 | 2015-05-07 | 2015-06-23  
4523693 | 2015-02-09 | 2015-05-08
```

Decired result

```
 | OrderID  |  Year  |  Month  |  Days  |      
 | 4523691  |  2015  |   1     |   9 |   
 | 4523691  |  2015  |   2     |   28 |   
 | 4523691  |  2015  |   3     |   31 |   
 | 4523691  |  2015  |   4     |   22 |   
 | 4523692  |  2015  |   5     |   25 |   
 | 4523692  |  2015  |   6     |   23 |   
 | 4523693  |  2015  |   2     |   20 |   
 | 4523693  |  2015  |   3     |   31 |   
 | 4523693  |  2015  |   4     |   30 |   
 | 4523693  |  2015  |   5     |   8 |
```

The script is working if run it with a where statement for each OrderID. So this is what I need help with, to run the quire without restriction on Order ID. Removing the restriction will cause the following error = Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
    DECLARE @FromDate as datetime  
    DECLARE @Todate as date  
    DECLARE @Month as date  

    SET @FromDate = (select fromdate from Order where orderid = '4523693')
    SET @ToDate = (select todate from Order where orderid = '4523693')  
    SET @Month = @FromDate  

    WHILE (eomonth(@Month) <= eomonth(@ToDate))  
    BEGIN  
    SELECT 
    OrderID
    ,year(dateadd(month, 0, eomonth(@Month)))
    ,month(dateadd(month, 0, eomonth(@Month)))
    ,case
    when eomonth(@Month) = eomonth(fromdate) then datediff(d, fromdate, eomonth(fromdate))+1       
    when eomonth(@Month) = eomonth(todate) then datediff(day,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, todate), 0) , todate)+1
    else DATEPART(dd, DATEADD(dd, DATEPART(dd, DATEADD(mm, 1, dateadd(month, 0, eomonth(@Month)))) * -1, DATEADD(mm, 1, dateadd(month, 0, eomonth(@Month)))))
    end as 'Days'
    FROM Order
    WHERE dateadd(month, 0, eomonth(fromdate)) <= eomonth(todate)
    AND FROMDATE IS NOT NULL
    AND ORDERID = '4523693'
    SET @Month = dateadd(month, 1, eomonth(@Month))
END
```

Comment: From the code you posted the only place I could see this happening is where you set the From and To dates. But I would ask why are you doing this in a loop? This should be a single query. Also, avoid using reserved words like "Order" as object names. It is painful to work with.

Comment: Don't use a loop for this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution. I keep a date CTE snippet around for queries that need to cover `gaps in date and time`. If you pour all dates into temp storage then your query becomes more natural to work with and readable too.

```
DECLARE @Orders TABLE(OrderID INT,FromDate DATETIME,ToDate DATETIME)
INSERT @Orders VALUES (100,'01/23/2015','04/22/2015'),(200,'05/07/2015','06/23/2015'),(300,'02/09/2015','05/08/2015')

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = (SELECT MIN(FromDate) FROM @Orders)
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = (SELECT MAX(ToDate) FROM @Orders)

;WITH Calendar as 
( 
    SELECT CalendarDate = @StartDate, CalendarYear = DATEPART(YEAR, @StartDate), CalendarMonth = DATEPART(MONTH, @StartDate) 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT CalendarDate = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -2, DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 1, CalendarDate)))), CalendarYear = DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate), CalendarMonth = DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(DAY, 1, CalendarDate))        FROM Calendar WHERE DATEADD (DAY, 1, CalendarDate) <= @EndDate 
)

SELECT 
    OrderID,
    CalendarYear,
    CalendarMonth,
    Days = COUNT(*)
FROM
    Calendar C
    LEFT JOIN @Orders O ON C.CalendarDate BETWEEN O.FromDate AND O.ToDate 
GROUP BY
    OrderID,CalendarYear,CalendarMonth,O.FromDate,O.ToDate
ORDER BY
    O.OrderID,O.FromDate,O.ToDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks Ross for the help. The solution works great for the 3 OrderIDs, but if I expand to all OrderIDs I get MAXRECURSION problems.

Comment: The value can be from 0..32,767. However, if you are going to be writing queries like this regularly then I would suggest that you create a Calendar table to hold all days for a large enough range to suffice your needs.

Comment: Hi Ross, The solution give wrong result if the period runs over 2 years. Example 2015-07-19--2016-07-18

Comment: And Days get wrong calculated. Above example show Year 2016, Month 1 = 30 days (should be 31)

Comment: @Mag I updated so the Calendar.CalendarDate is calculated as the end of day instead of start of day. That should fix the day off issue

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @FromDate = (select fromdate from Order where orderid = '4523693')
    SET @ToDate = (select todate from Order where orderid = '4523693')  

Change this to 
SET @FromDate = (select top 1 fromdate from Order where orderid = '4523693' order by fromdate desc )
    SET @ToDate = (select  top 1 todate from Order where orderid = '4523693' order by todate desc)
```